# CSS width calc function not working with website provider?

Tags: css

When I run my code locally, everything is formatted correctly.  When I try to upload the file onto GoDaddy, I'm getting an error on lines that have `width: calc(100% - (x)px)`.

This is my code that I'm getting an error on:

```
.banner-links, .banner-links-under, .banner-links-up {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 16px); /* Right here is where it says there's an error. */
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: right;
  height: 28px;
  color: black;
}
```

Is it a problem with GoDaddy not processing the `calc()` function?  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is my error in picture form:
[in GoDaddy's uploader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awmjp.png)

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Check my edit, I have uploaded a picture of my error in GoDaddy's uploader.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Does it work well on browser when you open the site?

Comment: You're right Nisarg, I just went for it and it worked, despite the errors.

Comment: Have you tried using an alternate means of uploading. perhaps some ftp like filezilla?

Comment: you are simply using an old editor that it's not configured with these new stuffs, that's all ... don't pay attention and move on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As evident from your screenshot, there is no error in CSS. It looks like the vendor's software doesn't recognize the [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function in CSS.

You can reach out to them if you want, and have them fix the issue. But I don't think it is necessary. As long as the CSS file is delivered correctly, and it works in the browser, this is not a problem.

> [image]